# Is there an existing Azure Policy that enforces Microsoft's Azure Naming Conventions?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Is there an existing Azure Policy that enforces Microsoft's published, recommended [Azure Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/naming-and-tagging)?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is that you can validate resource names against specific naming patterns and forbid the creation of resources which names don’t satisfy [pattern requirements.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/#naming)

Comment: I am aware of that.  I was just wondering if Microsoft had created an Azure Policy to enforce their own list of recommendations.  If it doesn't exist I'm going to suggest it in their user voice site.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in January 2020 the [Azure / azure-policy](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/tree/master/built-in-policies) repo on GitHub is updated each time changes are deployed to Azure.  At the time of this answer, none of the Built-in Azure Policies match the [Recommended abbreviations for Azure resource types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-abbreviations).

There is a generic [enforce-match-pattern](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/tree/master/samples/TextPatterns/enforce-match-pattern) that is documented to "Ensure resource names match the naming pattern" but you would need to deploy with the proper naming pattern, and more likely have a specific rule to match each Resource Type and that specific naming pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at my private project [here](https://github.com/matthiasguentert/azure-naming-convention-initiative), which hosts Azure policies that let you enforce Microsoft's naming convention.

It's still in the early phase, so pull requests and feedback is welcome.